# Proving congruent modulo

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

In my book there are three things that I need to prove. 
First of: $$a \equiv a \pmod n , \forall a \in Z.$$ I tried to prove it this way: $$ a-a = 0$$
$$0 \pmod n = 0$$
Is this correct?
Second one: $$ a \equiv b \pmod n \Rightarrow  b \equiv a \pmod n$$
I tried with this:
$$a-b=c$$
$$b-a=-c$$
$$c \pmod n=-c \pmod n$$
Is this correct? And the third one:
$$a \equiv b \pmod n \land b \equiv c \pmod n \Rightarrow a \equiv c \pmod n$$

No clue how to prove this so I need full help on this one.

Comment: You're not using the definition of congruence correctly. Recall that $a \equiv b \pmod n$ means that $a-b$ is divisible by $n$. You'll need to directly use this definition in each part of this question.

Comment: The three properties show that the congruence is an equivalence relation. Perhaps, the following helps : $a\equiv b\ (\ mod\ m\ )$ if and only if $m|a-b$. The third part can be solved as follows : $n|a-b$ and $n|b-c$ implies $n|a-b+b-c=a-c$

Comment: @Peter Yeah I've noticed that. As far as your help goes I don't know what $m|a-b$ means.

Comment: @AlexG. I have no clue what you're trying to say. Really new to maths so understandably I'm slow.

Comment: $m\mid a-b$ means $m$ divides $a-b$.

Comment: $m|n$ means there is an integer $k$ with $km=n$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr are you sure that you've given me correct information in your answer? Shouldn't it go like this: $a-a=0, and 0\cdot n=0, n\mid a-a, so a\equiv a\pmod{n}$?

Comment: No $c\ne-c\mod n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In proving any relation involving congruences or such properties of congruences, I'll advise you to use the definition of congruence and convert the congruence to the division form and carry out the necessary calculations, i.e. use $n|a-b$ which means $a-b$ is divisible by $n$ instead of $a \equiv b \pmod n $

As for examples, I am working out your three problems.

1. $$a \equiv a \pmod n , \forall a \in Z$$
   So $n|a-a$ by definition and hence $$n|0$$ which is always true. Hence proved.
2. $$ a \equiv b \pmod n \Rightarrow  b \equiv a \pmod n$$
   So $n|a-b$ by definition and hence $$n|b-a$$ or, $$b \equiv a \pmod n$$ Hence proved.
3. $$a \equiv b \pmod n \land b \equiv c \pmod n \Rightarrow a \equiv c \pmod n$$
   So $n|a-b$ and $n|b-c$ by definition and hence $$n|(a-b)+(b-c)$$ or, $$n|a-c$$ or, $$a \equiv c \pmod n$$ Hence proved.

Answer (score 3):

$$\exists k\in\mathbb Z:a=b+kn$$ is indeed an equivalence relation.

$$a=a+0n,$$
$$a=b+kn\implies b=a-kn,$$
$$a=b+kn\land b=c+k'n\implies a=c+k'n+kn=c+k''n.$$

Comment: One quibble: if we substitute $c + k'n$ for $b$ in the equation $a = b + kn$, we should obtain $a = c + k'n \color{red}{+} kn$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: yep, a branch of the cross has fallen. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a-a=0$ and $0\cdot n=0$, so $n\mid a-a$ thus $a\equiv a\pmod{n}$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $n\mid a-a$ rather than $0\mid a-a$?